# How to remove non-alpha-numeric characters from strings within a dataframe column?

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I have a DF column which has many strings in it. I need to remove all non-alpha numeric characters from that column: i.e:

```
df['strings'] = ["a#bc1!","a(b$c"]
```

Run code:

```
Print(df['strings']): ['abc','abc']
```

I've tried:

```
df['strings'].replace([',','.','/','"',':',';','!','@','#','$','%',"'","*","(",")","&",],"")
```

But this didn't work and I feel that there should be a more efficient way to do this using regex. Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use `str.replace`.

```
df
  strings
0  a#bc1!
1   a(b$c

df.strings.str.replace('[^a-zA-Z]', '')
0    abc
1    abc
Name: strings, dtype: object
```

---

To retain *alphanumeric* characters (not just alphabets as your expected output suggests), you'll need:

```
df.strings.str.replace('\W', '')
0    abc1
1     abc
Name: strings, dtype: object
```

Comment: `[^0-9a-zA-Z.,-/ ]` was what i was after personally

Answer (score 12):

Since you wrote alphanumeric, you need to add 0-9 in the regex.
But maybe you only wanted alphabetic...

```
import pandas as pd

ded = pd.DataFrame({'strings': ['a#bc1!', 'a(b$c']})

ded.strings.str.replace('[^a-zA-Z0-9]', '')
```

But it's basically what COLDSPEED wrote

Comment: That is correct, I had to add in the 0-9 and also the spaces since I wanted that but coldspeed's answer was first and is the correct method.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use regex

```
import re

regex = re.compile('[^a-zA-Z]')

l = ["a#bc1!","a(b$c"]

print [regex.sub('', i) for i in l]

['abc', 'abc']
```